# Swing gui not displaying, but no errors?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a java program that solves sudoku puzzles. So far all I have coded is a class that draws the board with swing, and another class that calls the gui class.

When I try and run the program nothing happens. No error messages are shown, but the gui doesn't show either. It immediately terminates.

Here is my code so far:

Gui class:

```
package sudoku;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui {

    Gui gui;
    JPanel board;
    JPanel subBoard[][];
    GridLayout layout;
    JLabel square[][];

    public void load() {

        gui = new Gui();
        gui.setUp();
        gui.buildBoard();

    }

    private void setUp() {

        layout = new GridLayout(3, 3);
        board = new JPanel(layout);
        subBoard = new JPanel[3][3];
        square = new JLabel[9][9];

    }

    private void buildBoard() {

        // set up board
        board.setSize(800, 600);
        board.setVisible(true);

        int mod = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                // add subBoards to board
                subBoard[i][j] = new JPanel();
                board.add(subBoard[i][j]);
                subBoard[i][j].setLayout(layout);
                subBoard[i][j].setVisible(true);

                // add textfields to each subBoard
                square[i + mod][j + mod] = new JLabel();
                subBoard[i][j].add(square[i + mod][j + mod]);
                square[i + mod][j + mod].setVisible(true);

            }
            mod += 3;

        }
    }

}
```

main class:

```
package sudoku;

public class SudokuSolver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.load();

    }

}
```

I tried running it in both eclipse and netbeans but got the same result both times. Why does this not work?

Comment: You have a class `Gui`, that has a member of type `Gui`?  That makes my head hurt.

Comment: You need to go through the tutorials as they'll tell you that you need to display components in a top level container. It's all explained there. Note, it's good to know now that no compiler errors and no runtime exceptions does not mean that there are no logic errors present.

Answer (score 5):

There is no displayable window such as a `JFrame` being used in the application.

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("New GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Gui gui = new Gui();
      gui.load();
      frame.add(gui.getBoard()); // add getBoard getter
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
});
```

Remove the class member variable `gui` within `Gui`. This is shadowing variables in the outer class `Gui` so use the latter instead. Also override `getPreferredSize` to give the `board` a size when `frame.pack()` is invoked.

Comment: Why `frame.add(gui.getBoard());` and not `frame.setContentPane(gui.getBoard())`; ?

Comment: Adding the panel at `BorderLayout.CENTER` will make it occupy the full client area as there are no other components added

Comment: Doesn't `JFrame` have `FlowLayout` by default?  I'm not arguing - just trying to understand.

Comment: @PM77-1: Reimeus is correct. `frame.add(...)` is equivalent to `frame.getContentPane(...)`, which is good enough for these purposes. And top level window contentPanes do use BorderLayout by default. 1+.

Answer (score 2):

Make `GUI` extend `JFrame` firstly. Then in your main method call `gui.setVisible(true);`.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame { }
```

Then in main.

```
Gui gui = new Gui();
gui.load();
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: and `board` needs to be designated as `content pane` for `gui` frame.

Comment: It's generally not recommend to extend directly from a top level container if you can at all avoid it.  Better to extend from something like `JPanel` which provides you with the flexibility to use the component in any way you wish...add it to a `JFrame`, `JWindow`, `JApplet` or add it as part of an already existing UI

Answer (score 0):

You can not show directly Jpanel. for show gui you must use JFrame or any other Window class(JDialog, JWindow...) and after that set visible property true.

setVisible(true);

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {
       Gui(){
           ...
           setVisible(true);
           setSize(300,400);
        }
        ...
}
```